# camel-rabbitmq: How to express multiple binding parameters in an URI?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

How can I express RabbitMQ binding parameters in an URI that describes a from point of a Camel path? 
The camel version is 3.0.1.

I have tried a URI like `rabbitmq://rabbitmq.dev.mycompany.net/myExchange?username=guest&password=guest&queue=myQueue&exchangeType=headers&vhost=all&autoAck=false&autoDelete=false&automaticRecoveryEnabled=true&args=arg.binding.country=CZ&args=arg.binding.type=myMessageType&args=arg.binding.x-match=all`.

All works fine except the `args` parameters. When I dived a little into the code, I found that the `RabbitMQEndpointConfigurer` expects the related 'args' (multi)value be stored in a map, but the URI scanner always encodes multivalues into a list with a (sub)names and value kept together in a single string. I haven't found any way to express a URI parameter with a map-formed value.

Comment: Can you try with a newer version, and if still a problem then create a JIRA ticket

Comment: Reproduced with Camel 3.2.0. Created a JIRA ticket CAMEL-15062.

Comment: FYI, I checked the linked ticket and the resolution was to create a map of the args in a bean and then reference that bean like `&args=#argsBeanName`.